# General solution of differential equation: $y'=\frac{(y+x+1)}{(2y+2x-1)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am relatively new to this lesson and neither I nor my class isn't very familiar with it. We have been given a simple equation and ordered to find solution using internet.
$$y'=\frac{(y+x+1)}{(2y+2x-1)}$$
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Put $y+x= v$. Differentiate w r t $x$ you get $y'=v'-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

It can be written as

$$2y'=1+\frac{3}{2y+2x-1}$$

or
$$2y'+2=3+\frac{3}{2y+2x-1}$$

from here, put
$$z=2y+2x-1$$
to get

$$z'=3+\frac 3z$$
or
$$zz'=3z+3$$
and
$$\frac{z}{(z+1)}z'=3$$